# How can I avenge my friends' deaths?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

Today when I started up Shadow of Mordor, it told me that my death has been avenged by one of my friends. What does this mean? How can I return the favor and avenge my friends' deaths?

Comment: This generally means that someone has killed your killer, and you can do the same for them.

Comment: I figured as much, but how? Did the same named captain happen to also spawn in his instance of the game, and Steam knew to tell me that "it's cool, that guy's dead", or... what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you die, there is a chance a "bounty" will be placed on your killer:

[image: Vendetta: Avenge the death of Chuck Norris by killing Golm Manhunter]

This is available for anyone in the game. Even randoms. So by default, if you ever see any of these, you will be avenging the deaths of friends by killing the target.

Comment: Implausible. Chuck Norris can't die.

Answer (score 0):

you are avenging the deaths of total players that are playing it i would say...non of my friends have shadow of mordor and the avenge trials pop up for me as well so i asume its world wide not just friends